# MySQLI returns nothing when some variables are inserted in array

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello I am trying to fetch data from my database using this code:

```
public function getAllConstitutionPages($id){
    $result =  $this->conn->prepare("SELECT para.id, para.pageFk, 
                                            para.title, para.subtitle, para.paragraph 
                                    FROM `constitutionpage_tb` page 
                                        JOIN constitutionpageparagraph_tb para ON para.pageFk = page.id 
                                    WHERE page.constitutionFk IN (?)");
    $result->bind_param("s", $id);
    $result->execute();
    $response["pages"] = array();
    $result->bind_result($id, $pageFk, $title, $subTitle, $paragraph);
    while($row = $result->fetch()) 
    {
        $page = array();
        $page["id"] = $id;
        $page["pageFk"] = $pageFk; 
        $page["title"] = $title;
        $page["subTitle"] = $subTitle;  
        $page["paragraph"] = $paragraph; 
         echo.$paragraph;//prints out the paragraph in the browser
        $response["pages"][] =  $page;

    }

    return $response;
}
```

The query selects 5 columns which I bind successfully with bind_result issue comes in with the while loop, for some unknown reasons when I add `$page["paragraph"] = $paragraph;` the query does not return anything not even an empty `pages` array, the moment I remove it I get all my data, there is nothing wrong with the query because I have tested it in phpmyadmin and it returns all the 5 columns including paragraph, the last time I had such a problem was because I had 2 a variable in the bind_result with the same name as the `page` array so it was consuming itself, but in this case I do not, someone help me detect my mistake

### Update

*After wrestling with the code I tried echoing `paragraph` from the loop and I realized its echoing successfully, what I cannot understand is why cant it be stored in the array, why is it that when I add it nothing absolutely nothing is returned not even an error message*

Comment: You are defining the array $page = array(); inside the loop. You should create it before and add the items looping as you are doing.

Comment: @GiacomoPittalis add your comment as answer

Comment: @GiacomoPittalis yes, the little arrays in one big arrays are easily converted into single objects, so ideally $page is one object

Comment: @GiacomoPittalis look at the getMessages() method on https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-tutorial/ people do this all the time

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by reviewing my data in the database, aparently on of the paragraphs has a `-` that had not been escaped.